# Azure Blob storage REST Api - How to write headers as string

Tags: rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am new to REST and I am trying to test a REST call to my Private azure blob storage.  I downloaded a small REST call testing program that asks for a URL and Headers (both as string).

I need to list all the blobs in a container using the method described here: [List Blobs (REST API)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135734.aspx)

I am basically wondering **how to write the Headers** (to include my Key to access the private container).

Thanks

Edit : The program I use to test REST calls is an Extension for Chrome named "Simple REST Client"

Comment: Can you share the code you're using?

Comment: honestly you might have an easier time using one of the available libraries that wrap around the REST calls (Java, .NET, etc)

Comment: Hi, I cannot use the standard libraries as my application is in Silverlight.  Those assemblies are not compatible... :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you should input it this way into that chrome plugin:
Authorization="SharedKey accountname:SharedKey" x-ms-date:2013-01-24T21:33:40 (Current Date)

At least according to this document:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx